# Is it important to estimate $\lambda$in Box-Cox/Yeo-Johnson?

Tags: data-transformation

I am reading about Box-Cox, Yeo-Johnson transformations.

I am looking at different choices of the power $\lambda$ for my models, and I just look at the qq-plot and pick the one that fits the best. Why? Because the reason I use these transformations in the first place is so my normality assumptions are met.

However, literature suggests that the parameter should be estimated in some way. In what way (for a gam model, eg.), and why is this important? Why not just look at the qqplots for some fixed values of $\lambda$ that are commonly used?

Answer (score -1):

Because in that case you are assuming you have some distribution with an unknown parameter. If that is the case, it is always important to optimize the parameter based on the data (typically through MLE).

There are cases when it is definitely reasonable to use a simpler transformation method (natural log comes to mind because that directly coincides with the log normal distribution also it is highly interpretable). But just choosing parameters because they look right rather than just estimating them is not the best course of action, from both an optimality standpoint and inference later on (you can make cases for using MLEs vs picking the parameters based on the QQ plot).

Comment: Why is it always important to optimize a transformation parameter rather than to (say) choose one which is interpretable? You say it's not the right course of action but it's not particularly clear to me that a great deal would be lost. Is there some study that compares the two and supports always estimating?